# I need to get a string between two strings using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have a string for example: `"GamerTag":"A Talented Boy","GamerTileUrl"` and what I have been trying and failing to get is the value: `A Talented Boy`. I need help creating a regex string to get specifically just `A Talented Boy`. Can somebody please help me!

Comment: You should always show your efforts even if it is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON? Then use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string methods:

```
string result = text.Split(':').Last().Split(',').First().Trim('"');
```

The `First/Last` extension methods prevent exceptions when the separators are missing.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/r184rw)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
\:\"([^\"]+)\"
```

This matches the semicolon and the opening quote, and matches any non-quote characters until the next quote.

Comment: I think you mean \:\"([^\"]+)\"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose s is your string (no check here):

```
s = s.Split(':')[1].Split(',')[0].Trim('"');
```

If you want to have a `Regex` solution, here it is:

```
s = "\"GamerTag\":\"A Talented Boy\",\"GamerTileUrl\"";
Regex reg = new Regex("(?<=:\").+?(?=\")");
s = reg.Match(s).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "\"GamerTag\":\"A Talented Boy\",\"GamerTileUrl\"";

var colonParts = str.Split(':');
if (colonParts.Length >= 2) {
    var commaParts = colonParts[1].Split(',');

    var aTalentedBoy = commaParts[0];
    var gamerTileUrl = commaParts[1];
}
```

This allows you to also get other parts of the comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to assume that your string is actually bigger than what you showed us and it contains multiple key/value pairs? I think this is will do what you are looking for:

```
str.Split("GamerTag:\"")[1].Split("\"")[1];
```

The first split targets `"GamerTag:"` and gets everything *after* it. The second split gets everything between first and second `"` that exists in that chunk after `"GamerTag:"`